# how to remove the base line on the yaxis of highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I need to remove the following encircled parts from my highcharts chart, one is the base line on the y axis and the other is the values label on the x axis. I've tried several things mentioned in the API but I haven't been able to achieve this yet.

[image]

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ftaran/jBHDM/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tickWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
                "startOnTick": true
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '<br/>' + this.percentage.toFixed(2) + '%';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Fail',
            color: 'red',
            data: [5]
        }, {
            name: 'Success',
            color: 'green',
            data: [2]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get rid of lines, you have to add these to your `xAxis` config:

```
lineWidth: 0,
tickWidth: 0
```

And to get rid of the "Values" text, add this to your `yAxis` config:

```
title: null
```

Here are the final configs and a link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBHDM/1/):

```
xAxis: {
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickWidth: 0,
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    }
},
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: null,
    "startOnTick": true
}
```

Highcharts can be confusing because which axis is the `xAxis` or `yAxis` can be not intuitive. Hope this helps!